# Compile lisp / scheme in Notepad++

Tags: lisp, scheme, notepad++

I'm pretty much into lisp at the moment, and unfortunately i'm only available to code on windows. Is is possible to let Notepad++ take care of the interpreting of my scripts, and display the output in the compiler window?

If yes, what interpreter would be the best to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'd consider picking up NT EMACS instead.  Does all that stuff, free, and if you get bored you can always run M-x psychoanalyze-pinhead.

If you're really doing Scheme, have a look at Drscheme.

Answer (score 5):

I second Charlie's recommendation. Get Emacs and SLIME. On Windows, I might get CLISP if SBCL gives any trouble. Also, [Lispworks Personal Edition](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html) has got a pretty cool IDE, you could try that.

Answer (score 3):

Like others, I suggest using Emacs for Common Lisp. The easiest way to get started is [Lispbox](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/lispbox/), which is Emacs + Slime + some Common Lisp implementation all fully featured and already configured.

For Scheme, the easiest way to get started is [DrScheme](http://drscheme.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use Notepad++, its plugin SDK might be worth a look. You could write a small Notepad++ plugin that uses ECL to provide an on board Lisp REPL, and by defining a set of callbacks from Lisp to the plugin SDK, you can have the coziness of Notepad++ with the scriptability of Emacs. Just an idle thought.

Links:

- [ECL](http://ecls.sourceforge.net): Its the "ECLS" sourceforge project.
- [Notepad++ plugin development](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Development_Quick_Start_Guide)

Answer (score 2):

Just install CLISP, open up a command window, go to the folder where your source files are and execute:

```
CLISP sourceFile
```

You can ease this process by creating a hotkey in notepad++ and a batch file.
(You might need something to keep the console window open too)

Comment: How do you interact with the REPL this way?

Comment: Make sure that you stay inside CLISP, just read the documentation on possibilities. (Another possibility is copy pasting code automatically to a CLISP REPL window)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Clozure very happily for a couple weeks.  If it's available for Windows, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I found getting slime (superior lisp interaction mode emacs) up and running in emacs a little difficult.  You do want slime, but the barrier to entry is a little high if you don't already know emacs--or even if you do!

Luckily, there's a much easier way.

Just download [Lisp in a Box](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/). It's a little tricky because they give you a table of Operating Systems and lisp implementations. My suggestion is to choose the Windows-CLISP combo in the lower right-hand corner, version [2.37](http://common-lisp.net/pcl/windows/lispbox-0.7-clisp-2.37.zip)--I found CLISP to be the easiest implementation to use.

[Paul Graham uses Clisp too](http://www.paulgraham.com/lispfaq1.html), which is good enough for me.

Once you've downloaded LispBox, just let the thing automagically install itself and then click on the **BAT FILE** file to run slime.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Notepad++ to run your code using Clisp for Windows.  Click on run and type . `clisp -i  "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and click on save. -i is to keep the clisp window open after execution.